# Why am I getting more items then what I store into my database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I inserted 9 Products into my db but this code output "products!" more than the amount that I inserted into my database. Any ideas on why this is happening?

SERVER CODE:

```
var Product = require('../models/product');


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var products  = Product.find();

  res.render('shop/index', {title: 'Shopping Cart', products: products});

});
```

HTML CODE

```
{{# each products}}
  products!
{{/each}}
```

I tried this code below but still output more repeatable "products!"

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     Product.find(function(err, docs) {
         var productChunks = [];
         var chunkSize = 3;
         for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
             productChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
         }

        res.render('shop/index', {title: 'Godspeed', products: productChunks });
    });
});
```

THIS IS MY OUTPUT:

> products! products! products! products! products! products! products!
>   products! products! products! products! products! products! products!
>   products! products! products!

Comment: It would be useful to see what code you are using to store the products in your db. Also, to be sure, can you delete all of the records from your db and ensure that you are starting from scratch?

Comment: In that last bit of code, what do you get if you `console.log(docs)` as well as `console.log(docs.length)`?  Are you 100% positive you only have 9 documents?